# Objective C Cocoa: NSTableView, how to show scrollbars always?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am creating a cocoa application with objective-c, in which I am filling a NSTableView which may have over 100 rows.

**Problem**

The scroll bars are not shown. How to show scroll bars always.

**What I have done**

In code:

```
NSScrollView *sv = [_tableView enclosingScrollView];
[sv setScrollerStyle: NSScrollerStyleOverlay];
```

I have also made the given below setting, but the issue still persists. Please help. Many thanks for your attention.

[image]

Comment: How many properties are there for NSScrollView if you look up the API documentation?

Comment: In the xib, is 'Show Horizontal Scroller' and  'Show Vertical Scroller' switched on and 'Automatically Hide Scroller' switched off?